# no graphical way to upgrade with a .deb files?

Tags: apt, snap, deb

im on 20.04 and sometime ago i couldn't just double click on a .deb file to upgrade an existing package... before in the old software manager there was an upgrade button but now both in snap and in the old manager (which both confusingly share a name and icon) there is only an option to remove, even though in the command line when i do apt-get install file.deb it works perfectly as it should. is there a default alternative or should i just install a 3rd party manager?

Comment: Use Software Updater to update the debs on your system. It's the default application for applying updates which have come from the archives. If you have an actual deb file, you can just double click it, to install/upgrade the package. What precisely isn't working with software updater?

Comment: There is a graphical deb package installer named `gdebi`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: i have a different deb file i want to install of a program i already have installed, the default application doesn't let me update only remove the current software